# Scala not reading Excel file

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi

I'm trying to read an Excel file using Scala with Apache POI. This code was working, but has since stopped. When ran, it just completes without error with exit code 0. I'm trying to read an Excel file and print out the Name and Address stored within. I'm not sure why the code is no longer running, would someone be able to help? Please see below, and many thanks in advance for your help.

```
var targetCell= ""
var nameCol: Int = 0
var addressCol: Int = 1
def main(args: Array[String]){
  val fileName = "Path to my file"
  val file = new FileInputStream(fileName)
  val wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file)
  val sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0)

  for(row <- sheet){
      for(cell <- row){
          if(cell.getCellType == Cell.Cell_Type_STRING){
            cell.getRichStringCellValue.getString.trim == targetCell){
                var response= row.getRowNum
                val nameCell: XSSFRow = sheet.getRow(response)
                val cell:XSSFCell = nameCell.getCell(nameCol)
                val addressCell: XSSFCell = tcCell.getCell(addressCol)

                println(cell + " " + addressCell)

          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `println` debugging at start of each block to see how far it is getting, or run it under a debugger such as IntelliJ. And checkout earlier versions of the code to see when it stopped working.

Comment: I have no clue about `scala` but I am pretty sure that this code line `cell.getRichStringCellValue.getString.trim == targetCell){` is syntactically wrong, isn't it? So this code cannot run at all.

Comment: https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo is a scala wrapper for poi - might be worth trying

Comment: @Tim thanks for the suggestion. When I add in println after for cell <- row it's printing out the value of each cell. When I set targetCell to a value it prints out certain values but it should be printing out all values with it set to "" which it does in another file

Comment: have you changed anything before stopping working? can you go back to the previous version?

Comment: my suggestion: start by making sure (println or debugger) that  you have more than 0 rows, and more than 0 cells per row. Then check if the cells are of type Cell_Type_STRING (basically, check that your code enters the main logic.

Comment: Fixed the issue, reverted to a previous version. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue, I reverted back to a previous version. There was no code change that would affect this snippet that I could see but it's working now.